# Display footer on every html print page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to display my footer on all print page but it display only at the last page nothing works for me. If any one have idea.

I have search out many css suggestion but nothing works for me.My technique display the footer only at the last page. but I need to display on all the printable pages.

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    height: 98.5%;
    width: 98%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 98.5%;
    width: 98%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 98.5%;
    margin: 0.3in 0.5in -0.1in 0.5in;
}
.footer, .push {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.attachment-watermark-print {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: .5;
}
</style>
```

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div class="push" style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
<span id="spnWaterMark" class="attachment-watermark-print">
Printed from My System
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your css,

```
.attachment-watermark-print {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
opacity: .5;
}
```

and in `.footer` class add these additional properties,

```
.footer {
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: thanks but this method still does not works for me it only show the water mark at the last page only in the print mode.

Comment: the above CSS does not my problem in Google Chrome ... Is There any solution for chrome please..securedeveloper